# GridPane adjustments in SceneBuilder

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Currently I am trying to make a GUI for my Zoo database application and I have no idea how to setup my `GridPane` to work exactly how I want it to work.
My problem is, I want to keep left side **always the same size** and only `TableView` and filtering `textField` below the table to be resizable.

On below screen you can see how it should look like from the start. Also, I have no idea how to center the lion `imageView`, just like I centered all of the `buttons` and `textFields` above.

Any hints would be great, thanks! :)

[image]

Comment: Use a SplitPane and set the max, min, and prefered width to be the same value for the left side. To center the image on the left side use a VBox as your left side root. When you get to your image, add a StackPane then your ImagePane to the StackPane.

Comment: Are you missing the Action Label and TextField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StackPanes are great at centering things. Also, if you set the minWidth, maxWidth, and preferedWidth of a root AnchorPane in a SplitPane. That side can no long grow with the rest of the scene.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="546.0" prefWidth="732.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" fx:controller="javafxapplication109.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.3078078078078078" layoutX="26.0" layoutY="120.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane maxWidth="200.0" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <VBox layoutX="29.0" layoutY="26.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Name" />
                        <TextField />
                        <Label text="Specie" />
                        <TextField />
                        <Label text="Age" />
                        <TextField />
                        <Label text="Cage" />
                        <TextField />
                        <Button maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add">
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets top="10.0" />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <StackPane prefHeight="180.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets top="20.0" />
                           </VBox.margin>
                           <children>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="150.0" fitWidth="180.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                                 <image>
                                    <Image url="@../img/java2.jpg" />
                                 </image>
                              </ImageView>
                           </children>
                        </StackPane>
                        <StackPane maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308">
                           <children>
                              <Label text="ZOO APPLICATION">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font name="System Bold" size="12.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </StackPane>
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="544.0" prefWidth="520.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView layoutX="65.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="45.0" text="ID" />
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="105.0" text="Name" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="108.33334350585938" text="Specie" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="41.666656494140625" text="Age" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Cage" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="124.33331298828125" text="Action" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

> Normal screen size:

[image]

> Fullscreen size:

[image]

> You can make the adjustments for your TableColumns.

Comment: Thank You so much! The only thing i changed was changing the table column resize property to constrained-resize (so the additional column is not created).